# How to ignore fields and properties using XStream serializer for C#?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xstream

The project I'm working on is using Xstream library in C# which is as far as I understand originally a java library.

Anyway I get the following error trying the `.toxml()` method on one of my classes:

> 'Couldn't set field myfild in object mynamespace.myclass. This operation is only valid on generic types.'

The field in question is of type `ICommand` and I don't want to serialize it anyway, so the question is: How can I ignore fields and properties in the serialization process? I know that in Java you use the tag `@XStreamOmitField` to omit a field, but I couldn't find a similar tag in c#. I already have tried things like `[HtmlIgnore]` without success.

Additionally, I was wondering if there is a documentation available for the .NET version, since the original Java version seems to be quite extensive.

Comment: What package/nuget are you using for your `Xstream` port?

Comment: @dbc Hard to say since this is some older code and the dll is directly copied into the project files, but it should be this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/XStream/ . 
Anyway, from what I can tell is, they used it to be able to serialize interfaces, which is the exact same problem I have with the standard xmlserializer.

Comment: That nuget says, [XStream Core Open Source library distributed under Apache.org 2.0 license.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XStream/) -- but they don't give a link to the source anywhere.  Without the source code or documentation it's very difficult to say whether there are any attributes that can suppress serialization of specific members.

Comment: Yep...that is exactly my problem :)

Comment: Is there any chance this was it?  https://code.google.com/archive/p/xstream-dot-net/

Comment: @dbc Hmm, yes..this looks like the same methods. I'll have a read, thanks so much!

Comment: Looking a bit further, https://www.nuget.org/packages/XStream/ looks like a build of an early version that lacks certain methods, specifically `XStream.AddIgnoreAttribute()` which is what you would need.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/vXuyl3 which shows that the method isn't present.  Could you download the source, build an up-to-date version, and add an assembly binding redirect?

Comment: @dbc Sorry for the veery late reply. I have a version that implements `Xstream.AddIgnoreAttribute()`, however it doesn't seem to work as intended. In general, I think I have narrowed down the source of the Problem: I have in several classes an `ICommand` Interface implemented as `RelayCommand` for MVVM style button commands. Within the `RelayCommand` class the serializer seems to fail. However, I have tried to add it to the ignore attribute types without any luck.

Comment: There are also some issues documented (but not resolved) in the archives about being able to use tags like `[xmllignore]` or `[field:NonSerialized]` it just seems, like the project never got as far as adding those features. (At least I couldn't make it work, or find any information on it)